# If else condition inside check in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to implement an `if-else` condition in my gatling check.

For example:- Below, I might get items array in JSON response as empty. So I need to check if items is empty. I need to execute another set of action. Can you please let me know how can I achieve this?

```
.check(
       jsonPath("$..items[(@.length-1)].id").saveAs("MyAlbumId")
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained on the Gatling ML:

When using a check, the default verify step is exists, so you have to use `whatever` instead if having your check find nothing is acceptable:
https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Checks#wiki-verifying

Then, you can use a doIf in order to perform a chain of actions on certain conditions:
https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Structure-Elements#wiki-do-if

For example:

```
doIf(session => !session.isAttributeDefined("MyAlbumId")) {
...
}
```